# About Regulated Functions

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

**Definition.** Let $X$ be a Banach space. A mapping $f:[a,b]\to X$ is called *regulated* if it has one sided limits.

In the setting of a Hausdorff topological vector space $X$, can we still define regulated functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in a Hausdorff topological vector space the one sided limit of a function is a defined object, you surely can do this, exactly as in the case of Banach spaces. (You even do not need the Hausdorff condition or vector space structure, as "having a limit" does not need this).